# Customize ckeditor in apex 4.1

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, oracle-apex

I am using the basic richtext editor (CKEditor 3) in APEX 4.1.0.00.3. I am looking for how to customize the editor toolbar. Specifically, how do I remove some items from the toolbar?

I am using the basic type of editor which only shows the bold, italic, underline, link and unlink toolbar items. I need to show **only the link and unlink items**.

I tried to hide the other items using jquery but it seems the document.ready fires before before the richtext area in my APEX page loads.

Comment: @TonyAndrews the question [has been rewritten](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14380916/revisions) since it was closed.

Comment: A couple of notes for you, for the future: Keep your question on the topic of the question. Don't include stuff that isn't necessary - the question should be able to stand on its own. Explaining that you've rewritten it is unnecessary. Second, please refrain from using signatures, or "thanks" or "thanks in advance", or asking explicitly for help. We realise you're here for help, to begin with. =)

Comment: @Shawn, yes I know but I couldn't see anything wrong with the original question either! :- "I was wondering if someone knows how to customize the CKEditor in APEX 4.1.0.00.3. I am using the basic type of editor witch show only the bold, italic, underline, link and unlink items. But, I need to show ONLY the link and unlink items. I also tried to hide the others items using JQuery but it seems document.ready function is load before the rich text area in my APEX page. Any help will be really appreciate.

Thank you by advance"

Comment: @TonyAndrews ...which is likely to be closed as a duplicate? Why not help the OP improve the quality of *this* question instead?

Comment: @J.Steen: I would if I could see anything wrong with it!  What IS wrong with it?  Surely it wouldn't be closed because he said "thanks in advance"?

Comment: I have edited the technical details back into the question. At this stage, I feel it's valid for being reopened. Perhaps the OP could add a bit of the code they tried, as a token effort? And also, consider investigating *how* the CKEditor is loaded, to see how it can be hooked into or manipulated.

Comment: I mean, I understand perfectly well what the question is. It does not seem in any way "likely [to] solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion", which is why is was closed.  I would happily answer it, except that I don't happen to know the answer...

Comment: "Thank you" guys for your contributions. I would suggest to the OP to propose rewriting alternative to the writers if they think something wrong in the post before closing it. This could help beginners to get involved in the community.

Comment: @jacques While that's a valid suggestion, there are just far too many questions coming through Stack Overflow every second to fix all of the "bad" ones. That said, no-one even seemed to ask you to improve your question before voting to close.